# Pythonic way of inserting lines to a file

Tags: python, file-io, insert

So as the description describes, I would like to add text to a file in a sequential manner. Say, for example I have a file like this (NOT HTML, this is just an imaginary language) lets call it ALLTHEITEMS:

```
<items>
</items>
```

say another file named ITEMS:

```
banana
apple
blueberry
pickle
```

And I already have read through items and have an array created:`['banana','apple','blueberry','pickle']`

I want to go through each item in the array and write it to ALLTHEITEMS in between the  tags.

So in the end ALLTHEITEMS should look like:

```
<items>
banana
apple
blueberry
pickle
</items>
```

What is the most pythonic way?

Comment: Show your way of doing that and we will tell you how to improve it.

Comment: What is the end goal? Should they be separated with newlines, like `<items>banana\napple\nblueberry\npickle\n</item>`, or stored some other way?

Comment: The goal is to have the file to look like:

<items>
banana
apple
blueberry
pickle
</items>

Comment: Have you looked at the [mmap module](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html)? I'd expect that if for whatever reason you can't just read the contents into a string, append to the string and then overwrite file with the whole shebang, mmap and regexes would be the way to go...

Comment: @TomaszWysocki It would be simple with a sed command, or in python for each item, I read ALLTHEITEMS line by line until I match <items> and then somehow write below that line the item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
with open(outputfile,'w') as out, open(inputfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        out.write(line)
        if tag_match(line):  #Somehow determine if this line is a match where we want to insert text.
           out.write('\n'.join(fruits)+'\n')
```

You *might* come up with a way to make it faster, but I doubt it is worthwhile.  This is simple, easy to read, and gets the job done.  "pythonic" enough for me :-)

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it the way I described so your answer is accepted!

Answer (score 0):

The most pythonic way for parsing markup is to use a suitable [module](http://docs.python.org/library/markup.html) to parse it.

Comment: There are no modules for a language that does not exist. Its a configuration file to be exact.

Comment: @Dan Do you control the config file format (is it a custom app)? There are a billion formats for config files (`ini`, `json`, `yaml`, you name it) - there are modules for these, and no reason to not use these formats if you can.