# Read a file and match multiple lines

Tags: python, regex

The text file is like:

```
    <field>
        </field>
```

I want to match the block and write something in between the two **field** tag. I have got the following code which is from [How to search for a string in text files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940032/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-text-files)

```
!/usr/bin/env python3
import mmap
import os

with open('sample.txt', 'rb+', 0) as file, \
     mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as s:
    if s.find(b'<field>\n<\field>') != -1:
        file.write("Hello")
```

My solution doesn't work even if I use **\t** to detect the tab

```
'<field>\n\t<\field>'
```

I think my issue is how to match multiple lines that have some space or tab in it. Thanks everyone.

Comment: (1) You can't insert data into a file, you have to rewrite it at least from insertion point to the end. (2) You call `find` but didn't use the position returned by it. (3) The position returned by `find` would be at beginning of `b'<field>`. (4) If you are a beginner in Python you should start with something simpler: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression matching a multiline block of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587345/regular-expression-matching-a-multiline-block-of-text)

Comment: You must refer to the mmaped file: mm= mmap.mmap(file.fileno(),...) . See the documentation, here is an example, too: https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from: [Pythonic way of inserting lines to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044927/pythonic-way-of-inserting-lines-to-a-file)

The solution doesn't use mmap. That's true we cannot insert data into a file, but we can replace the data.

```
        target = "<field>Hello</field>"

        with open(os.path.join(root, filename), 'r') as file:
            filedata = file.read()

        # Replace the target string
        filedata = filedata.replace('<field></field>', target)

        # Write the file out again
        with open(os.path.join(root, filename), 'w') as file:
            file.write(filedata)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this question: [Regular expression matching a multiline block of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587345/regular-expression-matching-a-multiline-block-of-text)

Your goal is simple enough using regexes. The following script finds `<field>` tags in the variable `html`, and puts `<text to put between the tags>` in between the tags.

```
import mmap
import os
import re

# do logic here

# test for what you want from variable s:

a = re.sub('<field>(.*\n*)<\/field>', '<text to put between the tags>', html)
```